# Spring Roo from WSDL?

Tags: gwt, wsdl, spring-roo

Spring Roo + GWT is very exciting but I'd like to use an existing Web Service as a backend so I was wondering if there is any way to configure Roo to use a WSDL as the starting point rather than the entity description (and have it wire in the Jax-WS calls to the service).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Spring Roo do not have support for this yet.

Comment: newest version of Spring Roo adds the @Service support but still there is no WSDL code gen yet ...